# Is Mahout 0.7 compatible with Lucene 4.0.0?

Tags: lucene, mahout

I'm trying to use the Mahout 0.7 Java API directly to retrieve vectors from my Lucene 4.0.0. index. However, when invoking the method `org.apache.mahout.utils.vectors.lucene.Driver.dumpVectors()` I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.index.TermVectorMapper` . And it's true; that class doesn't exist in lucene-core-4.0.0.jar, but it does exist in lucene-core-3.6.0.jar.

So am I correct in assuming that the problem is that Mahout is tightly coupled with 3.6.0 of Lucene, and it's not possible to do what I'm trying here, given these versions? Or am I crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Mahout 0.7 uses Lucene 3.6. There is [a patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1112) to support Lucene 4.0, but it not yet merged into source tree.

Comment: I applied the patch, and Mahout now plays nicely with my Lucene 4 index. Thanks!

Comment: If you'll have a time, please share your experience with it in comments section for this patch. thank you

Comment: I have the same question, but with Mahout 0.8 and Lucene 4.4. seems to be not finding the term vectors properly